# Read() doesn't work

Tags: pascal

Procedure read(s2) doesn't work

```
var
  s1, s2: string;
  h1, m1: integer;
begin
  read(s1);
  h1 := Strtoint(s1[1:3]);
  m1 := StrtoInt(s1[4:6]);
  read(s2);
  write(h1, m1);
end.
```

Compilation look like this

```
12:25
1225
```

It should look like this

```
12:25
(asking s2)
1225
```

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: Like this
    
    12:25
    (asking s2)
    1225

Comment: Where do you expect "(asking s2)" to come from?

Comment: read() is used to get information from user, first "read(s1)" is working

Comment: "Operator read(s2) doesn't work" ==> "I don't understand how 'read' works"

Comment: First, "Read()" is not an operator, it is a (pseudo-)procedure. Second, it is one of the basic routines in Pascal, and it most definitely works. But obviously not the way you think it should. And I am still wondering which Pascal allows the syntax `s[1:3]`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  I was wondering too.  Not FPC, apparently, but to my surprise it *does* accept the syntax `s[1..3]`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's PascalABC.NET. Yes I made a mistake, it is a procedure

Comment: @MartynA: `s[1..3]` is Extended Pascal syntax, AFAIK, a so called substring-variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables `s1` and `s2` are declared as strings, and these can contain any characters the user can type on the keyboard, and any number of them.  So, how do you imagine the program can tell, when the user pressses a key, whether it is supposed to be part of `s1` or `s2`?  Answer:  it can't.

To make your code work properly, use `readln` instead of `read`.  That way, when `readln` executes, the user has to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to tell the program to finish waiting for more characters to be typed.

Note that some Pascal implementations allow you to write something like this

```
readln(i1, i2)
```

where `i1` and `i2` are integers.  This will work if the user types two integers separated by a space or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, because then the reading code can tell where the inputting of `i1` ends and `i2` begins.

Also note that

```
readln;
```

by itself waits for the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which is a rudimentary way of getting the program to "pause".